# Incorrect values in array_words array

Tags: ruby

can you please advice me why array_words includes after abc input three times cab string? I expect that includes abc, bac, cab ...

```
str1 = gets.chomp
start_position = 0
max = str1.length - 1
array_words = Array.new

def get_str1(str1, max, start_position, array_words)
  for x in start_position..max
    
      pom = str1[start_position]
      str1[start_position] = str1[x]
      str1[x] = pom

      puts "Inside loop: " + str1
      array_words << str1 
  end   

  puts array_words
end
```

[image: Output]

Comment: Hi, thanks for you answer. Basially i got the point that those are pointers and i need to create another variable. But why in code below is different behaviour?

def add_values(array_new, str)
  for x in 1..10
    str = x
    array_new << str
  end
  puts array_new
end
add_values(array_new, str)

Answer (score 1):

In simple words: array_words contain 3 pointers to one object str1 which in the last iteration is 'cab'. You can test it yourself

```
      puts "Inside loop: " + str1.object_id.to_s
      array_words << str1
  end

  puts array_words.map(&:object_id)
```

Simpliest method is to create another object when adding to array:

```
  array_words << str1.dup
```

Answer (score 1):

Because `array_words` contains multiple references to **the same object**.

Minimal reproduction example:

```
[1] pry(main)> str1 = "abc"
=> "abc"
[2] pry(main)> array_words = []
=> []
[3] pry(main)> array_words << str1
=> ["abc"]
[4] pry(main)> str1[0] = 'x'
=> "x"
[5] pry(main)> array_words
=> ["xbc"]
```

You are appending the *same object* into the array each time, and then you are *mutating the object*.

An easy fix here would be to explicitly create a *new object* each time you append to the array:

```
array_words << str1.dup
```

(See: [`Object#dup`](https://apidock.com/ruby/Object/dup).)

---

On a separate note, whilst there's nothing inherently *wrong* with your approach, it's generally considered un-rubyish to use `for` loops. This language almost always provides "nicer" ways to implement things. For example, how about:

```
(0..max).map do |i|
  str1.slice(i, str1.length-i) + str1.slice(0, i)
end
  # => ["abc", "bca", "cab"]
```